# how to add another button to a premade android program (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

I'm using this [code](http://www.parallelcodes.com/android-game-tutorial/) but I want to make it 4 options per question. I also lessened the questions to 5. Can someone help? Here's the modified code. It doesn't run though :(

QuizActivity.java

```
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity {
    List<Question> quesList;
    int score = 0;
    int qid = 0;
    Question currentQ;
    TextView txtQuestion, times, scored;
    Button button1, button2, button3, button4;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        QuizHelper db = new QuizHelper(this);  
        quesList = db.getAllQuestions();
        currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
        txtQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        scored = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        times = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timers);
        setQuestionView();
        times.setText("00:02:00");
        CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(60000, 1000);
        timer.start();
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getAnswer(button1.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getAnswer(button2.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getAnswer(button3.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getAnswer(button4.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }
    public void getAnswer(String AnswerString) {
        if (currentQ.getANSWER().equals(AnswerString)) {
            score++;
            scored.setText("Score : " + score);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,
                    ResultActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
            intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        if (qid < 4) {
            currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
            setQuestionView();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,
                    ResultActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
            intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {
        public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            times.setText("Time is up");
        }
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long millis = millisUntilFinished;
            String hms = String.format(
                    "%02d:%02d:%02d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
                            - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                            .toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)
                            - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                            .toMinutes(millis)));
            System.out.println(hms);
            times.setText(hms);
        }
    }
    private void setQuestionView() {
        txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
        button1.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
        button2.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
        button3.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
        button4.setText(currentQ.getOPTD());
        qid++;
    }
}
```

QuizHelper.java

```
public class QuizHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mathsone";
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "qid";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; // correct option
    private static final String KEY_OPTA = "opta"; // option a
    private static final String KEY_OPTB = "optb"; // option b
    private static final String KEY_OPTC = "optc"; // option c
    private static final String KEY_OPTD = "optd"; // option d
    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    public QuizHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase = db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTA + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_OPTB + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTC + " TEXT " + KEY_OPTD + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        addQuestion();
        // db.close();
    }
    private void addQuestion() {
        Question q1 = new Question("5+2 = ?", "7", "8", "6", "5", "7");
        this.addQuestion(q1);
        Question q2 = new Question("2+18 = ?", "18", "19", "20", "17", "20");
        this.addQuestion(q2);
        Question q3 = new Question("10-3 = ?", "6", "7", "8", "5", "7");
        this.addQuestion(q3);
        Question q4 = new Question("5+7 = ?", "12", "13", "14", "11", "12");
        this.addQuestion(q4);
        Question q5 = new Question("3-1 = ?", "1", "3", "2", "4", "2");
        this.addQuestion(q5);
        // END
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    // Adding new question
    public void addQuestion(Question quest) {
        // SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
        values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
        values.put(KEY_OPTD, quest.getOPTD());
        // Inserting Row
        dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);
    }
    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        dbase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question quest = new Question();
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
                quest.setOPTD(cursor.getString(6));
                quesList.add(quest);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return quesList;
    }
}
```

Question.java

```
public class Question extends Activity {
    private int ID;
    private String QUESTION;
    private String OPTA;
    private String OPTB;
    private String OPTC;
    private String OPTD;
    private String ANSWER;
    public Question() {
        ID = 0;
        QUESTION = "";
        OPTA = "";
        OPTB = "";
        OPTC = "";
        OPTD = "";
        ANSWER = "";
    }
    public Question(String qUESTION, String oPTA, String oPTB, String oPTC,String oPTD,
                    String aNSWER) {
        QUESTION = qUESTION;
        OPTA = oPTA;
        OPTB = oPTB;
        OPTC = oPTC;
        OPTD = oPTD;
        ANSWER = aNSWER;
    }
    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }
    public String getQUESTION() {
        return QUESTION;
    }
    public String getOPTA() {
        return OPTA;
    }
    public String getOPTB() {
        return OPTB;
    }
    public String getOPTC() {
        return OPTC;
    }
    public String getOPTD() {
        return OPTD;
    }
    public String getANSWER() {
        return ANSWER;
    }
    public void setID(int id) {
        ID = id;
    }
    public void setQUESTION(String qUESTION) {
        QUESTION = qUESTION;
    }
    public void setOPTA(String oPTA) {
        OPTA = oPTA;
    }
    public void setOPTB(String oPTB) {
        OPTB = oPTB;
    }
    public void setOPTC(String oPTC) {
        OPTC = oPTC;
    }
    public void setOPTD(String oPTD) {
        OPTD = oPTD;
    }
    public void setANSWER(String aNSWER) {
        ANSWER = aNSWER;
    }
}
```

Then for activity_main.xml I added an android button with an id of button4.

```
<Button
       android:id="@+id/button4"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
       android:background="#fff"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="31"
       android:textColor="#000000"
       android:textSize="25.0sp" />
```

here's my logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: versionone.example, PID: 2252
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{versionone.example/versionone.example.QuestionActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 6 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 6 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
   at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
   at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
   at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
   at versionone.example.QuizHelper.getAllQuestions(QuizHelper.java:90)
   at versionone.example.QuestionActivity.onCreate(QuestionActivity.java:38)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You say it doesn't run. You either get a compile error, or a stacktrace at some point. Could you edit your question to include the compile error or the stacktrace please?

Comment: Try posting just the important bits of your code. The logcat quite tells you what's up. tl;dr

Answer (score 3):

```
    + KEY_OPTB + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTC + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTD + " TEXT)";
```

You just missed one comma after `KEY_OPTC` in your table creation sql.

Comment: the program still doesn't run :( i'm still getting the same logcat error

Comment: Try to delete your app from phone and then run it again. Place some breakpoints in your SqliteOpenHelper, to see if sql statement executes correctly. Look for SQLite exceptions in your logcat, they may not crash your app, but indicate a trouble with table recreating. If app fails on 6th column, that means that other 5 is ok, so your database hasn't been upgraded propertly